# How to solve this double encoding?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm developing a website using python to preprocess request and a MySQL database to store information.

All my tables are utf8 and I also use utf8 as Content-type.

I have this code to establish connection to the db:

```
database_connection = MySQLdb.connect(host = database_host, user = database_username, passwd = database_password, db = database_name, use_unicode = True)
cursor = database_connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SET NAMES utf8;""");
cursor.execute("""SET CHARACTER SET utf8;""");
cursor.execute("""SET character_set_connection=utf8;""");
```

Running a simple test on my GoDaddy hosting printing the results of a simple SELECT query like this:

```
print results.encode("utf-8")
```

Shows a double encoded string. (So all non-ascii characters are transformed into two different specials). But if I leave the encode statement, it gives an encoding error for each non-ascii letter.

Comment: How is the result being displayed? In a webpage? Are you SSHing in? At a guess, it's being encoded correctly, but then it's being displayed in an environment that expects a single-byte encoding like latin-1.

Comment: The results are displayed on a webpage. As it displays special characters I think the environment must be unicode compatible. The problem is, that it seems to be double encoded. All non-ascii characters are displayed as two other letters for example: "ó" (small o with acute) letters are shown as "Ã³" and "ö" (small o with diaeresis) as "Ã¶" but "ő" (o with double acute) as only a single letter "Å".

Comment: It's more complicated than just 'special characters', unfortunately. There are a lot of different character encodings, and the web browser uses HTTP headers and HTML meta tags to decide which one to use. If you're using Firefox, you can use View, Character Encoding, UTF-8 to override it. If this is the problem, then you'll probably need to fix your HTML templates.

Comment: The HTTP headers and the HTML meta tags are correct, so the browser detects it as UTF-8 as expected. Anyway, I tried to force some other encodings but none of them seem to be correct.

Comment: In that case, @Craig's answer is the most likely: UTF-8 encoded text is somehow being decoded as latin-1 or cp1252.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though `results` contains a Unicode string that was incorrectly decoded from a byte string coming from the database. I.e. when you read the data from the database, it decoded the byte string as Latin-1 rather than the UTF-8 it really is.

So if you fix the decoding of the database contents, then you should be in business.

Comment: You're right! I only had to decode the UTF-8 rows. I think it's a GoDaddy exclusive problem as they have an outdated MySQLdb version. Later versions have better encoding features. Thanks for all answers guys!

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this which I found on the internet during one of my own encoding hunts. You can keep on chaining encoding styles to find a fit.

Also, as others said, try fixing the source first. This hack is just to figure out what encoding is being actually returned. Hope this helps.

```
#this method is a simple recursive hack that is going to find a compatible encoding for the problematic field
#does not guarantee successful encoding match. If no match is found, an error code will be returned: ENC_ERR

def findencoding(field, level):
    print "level: " + str(level)
    try:
        if(level == 0):
            field = field.encode('cp1252')
        elif(level == 1):
            field = field.encode('cp1254')
        else:
            return "ENC_ERR"
    except Exception:
        field = findencoding(field,level+1)

    return field
```

Comment: If I call your function with field=row[0], or any other single field of the results, level 0 seems to be correct, but on the whole page it returns ENC_ERROR.

Comment: Whole page? Umm.. are you trying to encode the entire page as a string using this method and then render it? My understanding was that once you have converted the results into the correct encoding you could just display them. In that case it seems there are multiple encoding(s) involved. You can add more to the chain and add levels and see where you can get all of the content resolved. If possible, can you post the content of the page you are trying to render?

Comment: I use the Template class to generate the page content. All strings are object of class Unicode. I only call the encode method at the last step.